# How can I clear the log in error messages when the user doesn't refresh the page and simply closes/exits out of my modal?

Tags: reactjs

I've made a modal for a simple log in page for a website:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../assets/stylesheets/session/login_form.css';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {}
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.renderErrors = this.renderErrors.bind(this);
        this.handleDemo = this.handleDemo.bind(this);
    }

    // After authentication redirect user to home page
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.currentUser === true) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
            this.props.closeModal();
        }
        // Setting or clearing errors
        this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    // Hides scrolling when modal is mounted
    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.modal) document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }

    // Reactiviates scrolling when modal is unmounted
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    }

    // Render the session errors if there are any
    renderErrors() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(this.state.errors).map((error, i) => (
                    <li key={`error-${i}`}>{this.state.errors[error]}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    // Handle field updates
    update(field) {
        return e =>
            this.setState({
                [field]: e.currentTarget.value
            });
    }

    // Handle form submission
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        if (this.props.errors) {
            this.props.login(user)
                .then(() => this.props.openModal('login'));
        } else {
          this.props.login(user)
                .then(() => this.props.closeModal());
        }
    }

    // Handle demo user login
    handleDemo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const user = { email: 'demouser@nookbnb.com', password: 'password' };
        this.props.login(user)
            .then(this.props.history.push('/'), this.props.closeModal());
    }

    // Rendering component
    render() {
        let errors;

        if (this.props.errors) {
            errors = this.props.errors;
        } else {
            errors = {};
        }

        let emailErrors = errors.email ? <div className="email-error">{errors.email}</div> : '';
        let passwordErrors = errors.password ? <div className="password-error">{errors.password}</div> : '';

        return (
            <div className="login-modal-wrapper">
                <div className="modal-wrapper" onClick={this.props.closeModal}></div>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="header-wrapper">
                      <div className="close-wrapper" onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
                        <i className="close-button"></i>
                      </div>

                      <h1>Log in</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div className="main-content-wrapper">
                      <button onClick={this.handleDemo}>
                        Demo Log in
                      </button>

                      <div className="button-separator-wrapper"><p>or</p></div>

                      <input
                        type="text"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.update('email')}
                        placeholder="Email"
                      />

                      <input
                        type="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.update("password")}
                        placeholder="Password"
                      />

                        <div className="session-errors">
                            {emailErrors}
                            {passwordErrors}
                        </div>

                      <button type="submit">Log in</button>

                        <div className="no-account-wrapper">
                            <p>Don't have an account? <span onClick={() => this.props.openModal('signupFirst')}>Sign up</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

And I've successfully displayed the right error messages when the user doesn't enter a required field in the login form (an email and a password), but if I don't manually do a page refresh, the errors still appear on the form even after I close and reopen the modal.

How can I implement this modal in a way where it will automatically clear errors after I close and reopen the modal?

**UPDATE**

Per the answer below, I've added these two open and closing modal functions to help clear the errors:

```
// Opens a login modal
openLoginModal() {
    this.setState({ errors: {} });
    this.props.openModal('login');
}

// Closes a login modal
closeLoginModal() {
    this.setState({ errors: {} });
    this.props.closeModal();
}
```

And I've replaced places in the render where I'm using `this.props.closeModal()` and `this.props.openModal()` with my functions above. (For now I'm just testing this with closing the modal; since the modal doesn't have any errors when initially opened, I believe I just need to account for closing the modal right now)

```
<div className="login-modal-wrapper">
  <div className="modal-wrapper" onClick={this.closeLoginModal}></div>

    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className={errors.email && errors.email.length !== 0 ? 'form-errors' : 'form-normal'}>
      <div className="header-wrapper">
        <div className="close-wrapper" onClick={this.closeLoginModal}>
          <i className="close-button"></i>
        </div>
        ...
```

But error messages are still persisting when I open and close the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider having an `openLoginModal` method that clears any errors and then opens the modal:

```
openLoginModal() {
  this.setState({ errors: {} })
  this.props.openModal('login');
}
```

And then replace any occurrence of `this.props.openModal('login')` to use this new method (`this.openLoginModal()`).

Edit: If you need to clear the errors specifically on exiting the modal, you can do a similar thing by creating a custom method around the `closeModal` prop.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thank you for the advice/answer!

Comment: Hm, I've made a open and closing login modal function, but it still seems to be persisting :( I'll update my code above

Comment: Sure, I'll add it above

Comment: Oh interesting, it looks like you have errors from props and errors from state. Why do you have these in different places?

Comment: Actually, I'm attempting to work on some code from a group project so I'll need to look into why they did that; but would that be a good place to start debugging? :O Maybe asking for a solution to this bug is a bit hard, but if you have any good advice on where this bug could be coming from that would be awesome! I'll see if I can figure out what's going on with the two errors in the meantime...

Comment: Well, the errors you're displaying are form `this.props.errors`, so you'll need a way to clear those errors. You can usually do that by passing a state-setting function from the parent component where you're getting those props from